# is insertedIds array guaranteed to be in the same order as the documents inserted in an InsertMany?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am reading this doc:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/

Will the `insertedIds` property of the returned object contain an array that has the inserted `_id` in the same order as the documents were listed in the `insertMany` operation?

Comment: That depends on your query if you have set { ordered: false } then will get unordered insertion else it would be ordered insertion and returned array will be ordered

Answer (score 1):

By default documents are inserted in order, and insertedIds will be in order.

```
ordered: boolean
Optional. A boolean specifying whether the mongod instance should perform an ordered or unordered insert. Defaults to true.
```